# getting info out of hashtable in javascript

Tags: javascript, hashtable

quick question
I have a hashtable, and each key has an object that is devided into two parts: subject and query.
Im trying to get the values of the query and subject, but I cant. all I get is undefined.
how do I get the value?

```
function IntersectGroups(keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray) {

    allKeys = CreateSetWithAllKeys(keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray);

    var numElements = Math.pow(2, keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray.length);

    var results1= new Array(numElements);
    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
    {

        results1[j] = 0;
    }


    // Run for every key (for all groups)
    for (var currentKey in allKeys.items)
    {

        var linescontent="";
        var index = 0;

        // Run for every group
        for (var k = 0; k < keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray.length; k++)
        {
            var isGroupContained = keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].hasItem(currentKey);

            if (isGroupContained)
            {
                //Not relevent: Watch the data structures: sumElements += keyToGeneDetailMappingGroupArray[k].getItem(currentKey).length;
                sumElements += 1; 
                linescontent += currentKey.Query;//I get undefined
                index += Math.pow(2, k);
            }
        }

        results1[index] += linescontent;
    }
    return results1;
}
```

data example

```
Query   Subject

Crella_elegansContig_3  tr|Q8BUQ6|Q8BUQ6_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_10 sp|Q8CHY3-2|DYM_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_14 sp|Q9R1L5|MAST1_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_16 sp|Q8BGZ4-2|CDC23_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_26 sp|Q9CPS6|HINT3_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_29 sp|Q8BP67|RL24_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_31 sp|A3FIN4-2|AT8B5_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_32 tr|E9PZX7|E9PZX7_MOUSE
Crella_elegansContig_33 sp|Q6P7W0|SENP6_MOUSE
```

[image]

Comment: please add the data and the function header and the call of the function.

Comment: please have a look here: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be adding your info to `results1` but you are returning `results` which would be undefined.

Comment: sorry, my bad. edited my question.
thats not the problem

Comment: Is it still returning undefined? If it is, can you post some data to compare

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var currentKey in allKeys.items) {
    /* ... */
                linescontent += currentKey.Query;//I get undefined
```

`for .. in` will set currentKey the keys of the `allKeys.items` object (and prototype). Even if it is an array, it'll be set to the indices of the items, and not the individual items, and will always be a string.

There's not information in your code to tell what allKeys.items actually looks like, but if you're expecting to iterate over the elements, then either use `for (var currentKey of allKeys.items)` (requires an es2015 environment) or `for (var i of allKeys.items) { var currentKey = allKeys.items[i]; /* ... */ }`.